# What is the right way to parse HTML?

Tags: html, parsing, regular-expressions

I've heard, that parsing HTML using the [Cthulhu way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) is not very good. But what are the right ways to parse HTML? Or is it possible to parse it at all?

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html

Comment: Seeing as browsers parse HTML... what do you say? Is it possible?

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: By using a... parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or is it possible to parse it at all?

Some say it's possible, and that even webbrowsers use this feature to display web pages.

> what are the right ways to parse HTML?

Basically you need a parser able to express the idea that an html element can be composed of other html elements.

```
<div>
  some text 
  <div>
    nested element!!
  </div> <!--a regular expression cannot tell if this closes the first or second div-->
</div>
```

This cannot be done with regular expression. But you can do it with more general kinds of parsers.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Your answer forgets that “regular expressions” (the computer science thing) and “regular expressions” (regex engines like PCRE) are very different, and that it's perfectly possible to parse any non left recursive context-free language with PCRE or equivalent. So it's entirely possible to write a HTML parser with regexes, it's *just extremely difficult to do correctly*, so you're better off using an existing HTML parser rather than using a half-assed regex that fails on unexpected but valid input.